# How do you track a tab you open and do something after it closes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble finding a suitable answer to this question. Here is a shortened version of my code:

**html button**

```
`<button id="add" type="button">Add</button>`
```

**js listener**

```
$('button#add').on('click', function() {
    $('#form').submit();
});
```

**html form tag**

```
<form name="form" id="form" action="/path/to/page" method="POST" target="_blank">
```

This is opening in a new tab, and I need to refresh this page when the user closes the new tab. Do I have to open the new tab in a different way (like `window.open()`) to be able to do that?

Thanks, let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Don’t do a new tab or window at all. Why not just show a large modal within the same tab?

Comment: I would do that in a heartbeat. however, im not calling the shots for design

Comment: Then whoever is calling the shots doesn’t need to be in charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. And it has to be from the same origin.

```
$('button#add').on('click', function() {
  var w = window.open("","winName","width=1000,height=10000");
  setTimeout(function() { $('#form').submit();},100);
});
```

using

```
<form target="winName"
```

then in the new page

```
window.onunload=function() {
  if (opener && !opener.closed) opener.location.reload(1);
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I copied your code over and it turns out you accidentally put an `l` after the statement instead of a semicolon. I corrected it and it works! Thanks!